# Can I use Ubuntu 16.04 live usb to update and install packages in system installed Ubuntu 17.04

Tags: 16.04, live-usb, 17.04

I updated ubuntu from 16.04  to 17.04 yesterday.When I was asked while installing the upgrade whether I wanted to clean old packages I clicked yes and after fininshing installation system rebooted.I coud not use my mouse and keyboard in ubuntu after the install and now I am stuck as I can't even enter password.I can use my keyboard to unlock disk crypt  but after that I am stuck in password screen.It just seems frozen.Even cursor is not displayed.

I am considering using bootable USB disc Ubuntu but I have 16.04 live usb.

**Is there a way I can use live ubuntu USB to install,update or repair package on Ubuntu installed on my laptop?**